# How do I make a lexer rule for css short color notation?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

For a school project I am building a CSS compiler that compiles my version of CSS into regular CSS.

I want to allow user to write a CSS hexacode with three characters when the hexacode is only the same character.

`#ffffff`can then be written as: `#fff`.

An equivalent regex would be:

```
#([0-9a-f])\1\1
```

I am aware of the fact that there is also short color codes that will not be matched by this, like `#0f0` for Lime.

Comment: Why only if the character is the same? Why not allow `#abc` for `#aabbcc`? Note that CSS already supports this syntax.

Comment: @sepp2k I think that would also allow a lot of codes that do not have a color value asigned to it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "have a color value assigned to it". Everything from `#000000` to `#ffffff` is a legal colour in CSS. And even if that weren't the case, you're still allowing the users to write `#aabbcc`, right? So how would allowing them to write `#abc` break anything? And again, real CSS allows `#abc` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR does not support back references. The only way to specify the requirement that all digits must be the same is to spell out all combinations manually:

```
ThreeDigitHex: '#000' | '#111' | ... | '#fff';
```

In addition to being annoying, this also means that something like `#abc` would give you something like "Unexpected '#', expected ThreeDigitHex, ColorName or SixDigitHex", which isn't particular helpful.

A better alternative might be to just allow any three digits and then add an action that checks whether all digits are the same and produces a meaningful error (like "All digits in a three-letter hex code must be the same") if they're not.

All that said, I don't necessarily think that this particular restriction makes much sense. Real CSS allows `#abc` as a shortcut for `#aabbcc` without any problems, so it isn't clear why you'd put extra effort into making your version of CSS be less compatible with real CSS.